# Variable that allows override and "simply expandable"?

Tags: bash, variables, makefile, gnu-make

I have the following in my [GNU Makefile](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/GNUmakefile) around Line 73:

```
RELEASE ?= $(shell $(UNAME) -r)
IS_FEDORA22_i686 = $(shell echo $(RELEASE) | $(EGREP) -i -c "fc22.i686")
```

It runs fine on BSDs, Linux (Ubuntu and Fedora), OS X and Solaris. However, on Cygwin and MinGW, it produces the following ([thanks cxw](https://superuser.com/a/945149/173513)). Cygwin and MinGW use the Bash shell:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `echo 2.0.4(0.287/5/3) | egrep -i -c "fc22.i686"'
```

From the manual and [6.2 The Two Flavors of Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html#Flavors), I think I need a variable like:

```
RELEASE ?::= $(shell $(UNAME) -r)
```

How do I make a variable both optional an "simply expandable"?

Comment: The problem here is not a _make_ one. The output of _uname_ includes shell meta-characters. You therefore need to quote those to protect them from the shell.Something like `$(shell echo '${RELEASE}' | … )` (that formulation assumes `${RELEASE}` has no single quotes in it of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be:

```
RELTEXT:=$(<whatever command>)
RELEASE?=$(RELTEXT)
```

Even though RELEASE isn't simply expandable, you know it will always expand to fixed text.

Comment: You were on the right track, thanks. The following worked without complaints: `RELEASE ?= $(shell $(UNAME) -r)` and then `IS_FEDORA22_i686 = $(shell echo $RELEASE | $(EGREP) -i -c "fc22.i686")` (no parens around the variable in the shell command).

Comment: I don't think that will work! _make_ will first expand the `$R` macro, producing (presumably) an empty string. _make_ then passes`echo ELEASE | …` to `$(shell)`.